# LoadError: cannot load such file -- gserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I think I messed up one of my projects and now it won't run almost any command.

Initially I installed all through RVM. The Gemfile shows rails 4.1.3

After some time I think I may tried to update rails and started a couple of other projects which rails version is 4.2.0 and both run fine.

Recently I went back on the first project to deploy it. I was configuring Capistrano when I noticed that I couldn't run any development commands on my working machine. First I tried to run the server but this error appeared:

```
$ rails server

bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/axl/coding/bfq/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

So I thought maybe I screw something with Capistrano so I returned to branch master but the error was still there.

Any rake call returns this:

```
$ rake db:setup
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.3.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/home/axl/coding/bfq/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/axl/coding/bfq/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/axl/coding/bfq  fiscal-quadrum/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/axl/coding/bfq/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/axl/coding/bfq/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/axl/coding/bfq/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Prepending `bundle exec` as suggested shows another error. For example:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:setup
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- gserver
/home/axl/coding/bfq/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/axl/coding/bfq/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/axl/coding/bfq/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

There are similar cases, error `bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH` is related to spring gem. Running rake rails:update:bin seems to help but I can't run it since rake doesn't work at all.

So I tried reinstalling RVM. But nothing changed. I even removed RVM and installed Rbenv. But everything is exactly the same.

Versions inside the project:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

$ gem --version
2.4.5

$ rake --version
rake, version 10.4.2

$ rails --version
Rails 4.1.6
```

`bundle update` does some updates but after that executing rake shows the same error as prepending `bundle exec`:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- gserver
/home/axl/coding/bfq/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/axl/coding/bfq/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And there is nothing useful googling `LoadError: cannot load such file -- gserver`

Please, help me :'(

Comment: Revert the repository to a clean state and just run `bundle`.  This will make sure all your dependencies are present.  Running `bundle update` blindly can break your project in subtle ways.  After running `bundle` try `bundle exec rails s` and see if the server starts.  Let us know if anything changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shame on me. I didn't define ruby local version for the project.

When using RVM:

```
$ rvm install 2.1.1
$ rvm use 2.1.1
```

For Rbenv:

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.1
$ rbenv local 2.1.1
```